# binomial coefficient: maximum value

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, optimization, binomial-coefficients

For $n\rightarrow \infty$ we consider
$$f(p)=\sum_{j=c}^n {n\choose j} p^j (1-p)^{n-j}.$$
We are interested in $\hat{p}:=\arg \max_p f(p)$.

Can we say something about $\hat{p}$ dependent on $n$ and $c$ without further assumptions?
Can we say something about $\hat{p}$ if we assume that $\hat{p}:=\arg \max_{p \ : \ np \gg 1} f(p)$.

Comment: Have you tried to calculate the value for some small values of $n$ and $c$?

Comment: yes. And somehow I get, that this value is maximal for $\hat{p}=\frac{1}{2}$. Is this always true?

Comment: Is $p$ allowed to be less than $0$ or larger than $1$? In that case, you want to make $|p-\frac 12|$ a large number.

Comment: When $0\leq p\leq 1$, the sum is always at most $1$, and it is $1$ exactly when $p=1$, independent from $c$. (If this is the case, I will write down a longer answer explaining.)

Comment: No, $p$ Needs to be in $(0,1)$.
My Problem is somehow relating to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/847338/approximation-of-expectation-of-non-linear-but-polynomial-function . My Problem is that I want to find an estimate for $E_p[f(p)]$ when we think of $p$ as a random variable taking on values between 0 and 1. I thought that it might help me to write
$E_p[f(p)]\leq f(\hat{p})$, but I'm not sure. Because if we have $f(1)=1$, then this seems to be too trivial. 
What about if $$n^{-1} \ll p \ll n^{-\frac{1}{c}}?$$

Answer (score 1):

The binomium of Newton tells us that
$$
(x+y)^n=\sum_{i=0}^n \binom n i x^i y^{n-i}
$$
setting $x=p$ and $y=1-p$ yields
$$
1 = \sum_{i=0}^n \binom n i p^i(1-p)^{n-i}
$$
Because all terms on the right are non-negative, we see that this is maximal (we then have equality) when we start summing at $c=0$. When $n\geq c>0$, we can set $p=1$, to obtain
$$
\sum_{i=c}^n \binom n i p^i(1-p)^{n-i}=0+0+\cdots +0+\binom nn p^n 0^0 = 1
$$
(We assume here that $0^0$ is $1$, because there is one way to take zero out of zero objects.) Thus, we achieve the maximum at $p=1$, independent from $c$. When $c=0$, i doesn't matter what $p$ is.

A plot with $n=10$ and $c=0$ to $10$:
[image: plot]

Comment: thank you for your answer. That helps me a lot understanding this Problem. But to get an answer to my Problem I Need to have a non-trivial case ($p=1$ is trivial). 

So could one say something if one restricts $p$ to some Domain, e.g. $n^{-1} \ll p \ll n^{-\frac{1}{c}}$, thus excluding the trivial cases?

Comment: Some small examples with mathematica show that you still want to have $p$ as large as possible. Maybe you can prove that the derivative with respect to $p$ is always positive for $0\leq p\leq 1$.

Comment: But somehow, for $p$ small enough, $f(p)$ gets bigger as well? I thought that is what I got when I tried it on Wolfram Alpha. 
You say that if we have the restriction that $p \ll n^{-\frac{1}{c}}$, then we should choose $p \sim n^{-\frac{1}{c'}}$ for $c'<c$?

Comment: This example Shows that bigger $p$ is not always better:
$n=100$, $c=5$, 
$p=0.6$ yields $f(p)=0.00002656..$
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bj%3D5%7D%5E%7B100%7D+%7B100+%5Cchoose+j%7D+0.6%5Ej+0.3%5E%7B100-j%7D
and $p=0.1$ yields $f(p)=0.9762889...$
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bj%3D5%7D%5E%7B100%7D+%7B100+%5Cchoose+j%7D+0.1%5Ej+0.9%5E%7B100-j%7D

By the way: I tried but I think derivatives are difficult. A more suitable way seems to be to look at $\frac{f(p)}{f(p+1)}$. But even though, I'm not sure how this asymptotically works.

Comment: That's interesting. My own plots suggest otherwise. See edit.

Comment: So where's my mistake?

Comment: @user136457 $0.6+0.3\neq 1$.

Comment: @Ragnar user136457 writes above, that $p \in (0,1)$. But I´m out.

Comment: Oh, I typed 0.6 and 0.3 instead of 0.6 and 0.4. 
So then I get for $p=0.6$ a bigger number. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bj%3D5%7D%5E%7B100%7D+%7B100+%5Cchoose+j%7D+0.6%5Ej+0.4%5E%7B100-j%7D
So this is no counterexample what will Support your answer.
Sorry for that silly mistake

Comment: @user136457, those things just happen. I think a plot will have to do. I don't have time and motivation for a proof right now.

Comment: I am confused now. I tried to compute the derivatives, and I thought that $f''(p)\geq 0$ for $c \geq 2$. But your plot Shows that this is not true. I am confused..

Comment: Only the first derivative has to be positive for f to be increasing.

Comment: Yes. But if the second derivative is positive, then the function should be convex, shouldn't it? But it is obviously not. 
Ok, the function is monotonically increasing in $p$. Is it also convex for $c \geq 2$?

Comment: But in fact, it seems to be quite hard to Show that the derivative is $>0$, isn't it?